# Apache Mod Rewrite Rule Special Condition

Tags: mod-rewrite

Im trying to redirect an old domain to its noew domain but there are some rules wheich I need to put in place and so far I havn't managed to get it quite right.

the old domain e.g www.old-domain.com has hundreds of folders names after UK towns like this:

www.old-domain.com/sheffield/
www.old-domain.com/london/
www.old-domain.com/essex/

inside each of these folders contains an index.html file and possible other directoreis and files.

I needs to redirect them to the new domain in such a way so that old domain/town maps to new domain/town but old domain/town/index.html doesnt put index.html on the new domain end however if the path after the town is anything other than index.html to redirect to it on the new domain.
Sorry that isn't the easiest to explain and not the easiest to read and undeerstand Im sure.

**www.old-domain.com/sheffield                                =>   www.new-domain.com/sheffield**

**www.old-domain.com/sheffield/                               =>   www.new-domain.com/sheffield/**

www.old-domain.com/sheffield/index.html                     =>   www.new-domain.com/sheffield/

www.old-domain.com/sheffield/main.html                      =>   www.new-domain.com/sheffield/main.html

www.old-domain.com/sheffield/innerFolder/                   =>   www.new-domain.com/sheffield/innerFolder

www.old-domain.com/sheffield/innerFolder/file.php           =>   www.new-domain.com/sheffield/innerFolder/file.php

The two in bold above I managed to get working by this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sheffield/(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/sheffield/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However Im really struggling to get old-domain.com/sheffield/index.html to not put .index.html on the new domain.

Can anyone shed any light on this before I pull my hair out staring at mod rewrite tutorial for any more hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After roughly 4-5 hours of trying different combniations and reading god know how many rewriterule tutorials I managed to get there. Heres the htacess file for just 3 locations which all work wonderfully now.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^sheffield\/index\.html http://www.new-domain.co.uk/sheffield/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^sheffield/(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.co.uk/sheffield/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^bolton\/index\.html http://www.new-domain.co.uk/bolton/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^bolton/(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.co.uk/bolton/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^coventry\/index\.html http://www.new-domain.co.uk/coventry/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^coventry/(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.co.uk/coventry/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unless you have some of the directories that will be forwarded differently I would be tempted to simplify it further:

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/index\.html http://www.new-domain.co.uk/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Thanks Germann.  I see your logic.  I cant do this at the minute as we are not redirecting all the locations in one go.  The bods here are rather bothered about the SEO rankings so we have done it to about 10 of the locations of about 3500.  However when we go for the full on swap over I'll certainly come back and look at your example again. thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The rewrite rules are processed on first matched basis.
You can put your exception before the main rule

Comment: Thanks for this. Mod Rewrite is like a mine field of complexity. Its on par with regex...just tons of intricate rules and random jargon whaich almost everytime takes ages to get the exact pattern your looking for.  However I did work it out and below is what I did.